# Why undefined method happen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I can't figure out why error occur such as 'undefined method `areaname' for nil:NilClass'.

Here's the error.

[image]

And code of view(.slim) is like this.

```
- @areas.each do |area|
  h2 = area.area_translations.with_lang.first.areaname
  table
    thead
```

And the controller is like this.

```
class AreaController < ApplicationController
  def index
        @areas = Area.all
  end

  def show
        @areas = Area.where(areaid: params[:id]) || []
  end
end
```

The data is like this.

[image: area]

[image: area_translation]

Any helps are welcomed. I'd appreciate if you give some advice.

cf. Model of Area and AreaTranslation

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :area_translations
        has_many :restaurants
end

class AreaTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :areas

        scope :with_lang , -> { where(lang: I18n.locale )}
end
```

Comment: Maybe scope "with_lang" limits the area_translations. Can you get code for "with_lang"

Comment: All your area record has area_translations.. in the picture the area 3 not have area_translations.. When the asocc no exists it returns nil.. you need wrapper it  into try function to avoid the errors and shows blank or empty

Comment: Oops! I check out my table a while ago, you're BINGO! Really, thank you.Without your help, I'm still stuck on it.